# Renaming a base branch in github

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I am trying to correct a typo i.e. spelling mistake in the name of of github fork I have created. Drop a "t" from `gwt-hightchart-dashboard-demo` to `gwt-highchart-dashboard-demo`

I am not able to find out how to do this simple exercise after going through a few google/stackoverflow search.

1. Is this possible?
2. Is this possible via GitHub web GUI? How?
3. Is this possible via GitHub Windows GUI? How?
4. Is this possible via Git command prompt? How?

Reference the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think its possible to do this via the GUI yet but you can do this locally and push changes:

```
git branch -m gwt-hightchart-dashboard-demo gwt-highchart-dashboard-demo
```

You can just use the built in branch renaming facility to do this

```
git branch -m old_name new_name
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to use couple of other additional steps. After branch command i had two branches ( one with old and another with new name ). I changed from github web gui "Settings" to use the new one as default and dropped the old branch using git push origin :gwt-hightchart-dashboard-demo

Comment: @SSR Thanks a lot. I just couldn't find out how to make GitHub use my master branch as actual master branch instead of the test branch. No idea why that second branch was considered master in the first place. It took me about 1 1/2 hours of searching until I found your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your repos Settings >> Options and look for "Default Branch" selection box.  It will have a list of all your branches.  Changing this will edit your base branch.